# Algorithm to determine weak/good/strong password

Tags: javascript, security, passwords

Open source javascript algorithm to feedback user on the quality of the password he is choosing.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392928/how-do-you-compute-password-complexity

Comment: A slight aside, but here's an interesting recent article from security god Bruce Schnier regarding password strength on the web.
http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/strong_web_pass.html

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://simplythebest.net/scripts/ajax/ajax_password_strength.html)'s one and [another](http://phiras.wordpress.com/2007/04/08/password-strength-meter-a-jquery-plugin/)

Answer (score 3):

I know one open source [Meter](http://www.passwordmeter.com/)
And this is the best. [Try this](http://www.passwordmeter.com/)

Comment: Yes, it is the best and you can use it under GPL open source License.

Comment: 25 spaces = 100% good. Other similar situations too: 5555555555555555 = 0%, 5555555555555555f = 52%, 5555555555555555ff = 82%, but ff5555555555555555 = 0% and f5555555555555555 = 52%. WTF?