# Is there a .net method to check a user password for simplicity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, passwords

I was wondering if there's a built-in method in C# .NET framework to check if a string, representing a new user password is too simple?

For instance, stuff like "1234" or "qwerty" or "33333" is too simple.

PS. I obviously can code all this myself. I was just curious, if there's something built into the platform that can do this for me before I begin.

Comment: No there is not. There are some encryption classes though that require keys to be under certain conditions but i quess thats missing the point...

Comment: See also [How do you compute password complexity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392928/how-do-you-compute-password-complexity) and [What is the best way to check the strength of a password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75057/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-the-strength-of-a-password)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [MembershipProvider.PasswordStrengthRegularExpression property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.passwordstrengthregularexpression.aspx) in combination with the [MinRequiredPasswordLength](http://MembershipProvider.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters%20Property) and [MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.minrequirednonalphanumericcharacters.aspx) to make sure the password meets your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

there is no built-in method in C# but you can easily setup a regular expression that checks:

At least 7 chars
At least 1 uppercase char (A-Z)
At least 1 number (0-9)
At least one special char

```
public static bool IsPasswordStrong(string password)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(password, @"^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).*$");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what does @ mean in front of the string?

Comment: -1 for bad policy. It allows many weak passwords, and even worse, it rejects many strong passwords. For example it'd reject my truecrypt password, and that has an entropy of about 80 bits.

Comment: @ahmod0 '@' indicates a verbatim string literal which tells the compiler to ignore escape characters in the string. Read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx for more info.

Comment: @Bigfellahull thanks for pointing it out. I was too trying to understand what he meant in that regexp. Since regexps are also used in your solution, can you suggest a "good" regexp?

Comment: I can't I'm afraid. It would depend entirely on your circumstances. Plus I am not that strong with reg ex. I think you would be best off asking another question specifically about the reg ex which you can then use with the PasswordStrengthRegularExpression property I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expressions](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) to define a complexity format for your password

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a Regular Expression validator to make sure that it contains atleast one special character (or whatever you have in mind).