# Password complexity requirements using regex

Tags: c#, regex, passwords

I need to use regex in order to validate that a password is of the correct complexity as set out in the guidelines from this [Microsoft article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786468(ws.10).aspx).

> Passwords must contain characters from **three** of the following **five** categories:
>
> ◦ Uppercase characters of European languages (A through Z, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters)
>
> ◦ Lowercase characters of European languages (a through z, sharp-s, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters)
>
> ◦ Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
>
> ◦ Nonalphanumeric characters: ~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|(){}[]:;"'<>,.?/
>
> ◦ Any Unicode character that is categorized as an alphabetic character but is not uppercase or lowercase. This includes Unicode characters from Asian languages.

I have had a play using my limited regex experience and various articles I have founding floating around the internet but haven't really been able to work out how to get this to work.

Below is some regex that I have tried that can create be used to create a password, but I'm not sure if this is along the right lines for achieving the above, I am thinking there must be a much nicer way of doing this.

```
    [A-Z][\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\_\\-\\+\\=\\`\\|\\\\\\(\\)\\{\\}\\[\\]\\:\\;\\\"\\'\\<\\>\\,\\.\\?\\/][0-9]{6}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Might not be as fast, but it will be much easier to improve and maintain if instead of a horrible RegEx you use a method which checks each requirement separately

Comment: don't use regex if it's not required here; just make validation method: convert password to ascii and check each char if it is in a validation list precompiled by you and having all the valid char values (value range)

Comment: Yep, I agree, this regex will be horrible to modify if needed...

Comment: check this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359228/is-there-a-net-method-to-check-a-user-password-for-simplicity or https://www.codeproject.com/tips/222203/customizable-password-policy-csharp

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I will take a look at the suggestions and see if I can get them working :)